# Regular Expressions (regex) Remove the word "and", Non Alphanumeric Characters and White Spaces from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

In Python, I'm attempting to clean (and, later compare) artists names and want to remove:

1. non alpha characters, or
2. white spaces, or
3. the word "and"

INPUT STRING: `Bootsy Collins and The Rubber Band`

DESIRED OUTPUT: `BootsyCollinsTheRubberBand`

```py
import re

s = 'Bootsy Collins and The Rubber Band'
res1 = re.sub(r'[^\w]|\s|\s+(and)\s', "", s)
res2 = re.sub(r'[^\w]|\s|\sand\s', "", s)
res3 = re.sub(r'[^\w]|\s|(and)', "", s)

print("\b", s, "\n"
      , "1st: ", res1, "\n"
      , "2nd: ", res2, "\n"
      , "3rd: ", res3)
```

```
Output:
Bootsy Collins and The Rubber Band 
 1st:  BootsyCollinsandTheRubberBand 
 2nd:  BootsyCollinsandTheRubberBand 
 3rd:  BootsyCollinsTheRubberB
```

Comment: The solution regex provided by the answers here should work also for other regex flavor/variety (e.g. PCRE, ECMAScript, Golang, java) as well. However, the title and question contents have been added with the particular Python flavor of the syntax used. This is to avoid people familiar with other regex flavor of other languages to misinterpret this question was caused by typo and consider it non-reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support the rules that you set out, instead of just on the sample text quoted, you need a more general regex with the correct flags setting for `re.sub` call:

```
re.sub(r'\band\b|\W', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

### Explanation

- The flag `re.IGNORECASE` is set so that you can also remove "And" (and other uppercase/lowercase combination variations) in the sentence.  In case you want to remove only "and" but not any variations of it, you can remove this flag setting.
- `\band\b` the word "and" enclosed with word boundary token `\b` on both sides.  This is to match for the 3 characters sequence "and" as an independent word rather than being a substring of another word.  Using `\b` to isolate the word instead of enclosing the word within white spaces like `\s+and\s` has the advantage that the `\b` option can also detect also word boundary in strings like `and,` while `\s+and\s` can't do.  This is because comma is not a white space.
- As white space `\s` is also a kind of non-word `\W` (since word `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), you don't need separate regex tokens for both.  `\W` already includes `\s`.  So, you can simplify the regex without separately using `\s`.

### Demo

***Test case #1:***

```
s = 'Bootsy Collins and The Rubber Band'
res = re.sub(r'\band\b|\W', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(res)

Output:
'BootsyCollinsTheRubberBand'
```

***Test case #2*** ('And' got removed) :

```
s = 'Bootsy Collins And The Rubber Band'
res = re.sub(r'\band\b|\W', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(res)

Output:
'BootsyCollinsTheRubberBand'
```

***Test case #3*** ('and,' [with comma after 'and'] got removed)

```
s = 'Bootsy Collins and, The Rubber Band'
res = re.sub(r'\band\b|\W', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(res)

Output:
'BootsyCollinsTheRubberBand'
```

***Counter Test case:*** (regex using white space `\s+` or `\s` instead of `\b` for word boundary)

```
s = 'Bootsy Collins and, The Rubber Band'
res = re.sub(r'\s+(and)\s|\W', '',s)
print(res)

Output:   'and' is NOT removed
'BootsyCollinsandTheRubberBand'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first two regular expressions don't match the " and " because when arriving at that position in the string, the `\s` part of the regex will match the space before "and" instead of the `\s+(and)\s` part of your regex.

You simply need to change the order, so that the latter is tried first. Also, `\s` is part of `[^\w]`, so you don't need to match `\s` separately. And finally, `\W` is the shorter form of `[^\w]`. So use:

```regex
\s+(and)\s|\W
```